# UIScrollView clickable but not scrollable

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, selector, uigesturerecognizer

I have a ScrollView which behaves like a Slide Show. It automatically slides to the next image and in the end it goes back. But while this happens i don't want the user to slide in the scrollview him self. What i do want is to make each image that slides clickable so that the user can open a specific image for example for more details.

The default setting for the scrollview is userinteractionEnabled = FALSE. No user interaction allowed so the user cant scroll. But this also disables the click on image action. When i set it to true i can click on the image but i am also able to scroll again. So what's the best way for this?

I have considered adding a transparant UIView over the scrollview and make this clickable and check which item was shown in the scrollview. But is there another way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userInteractionEnabled` should be set to `YES`, however, you can set the `scrollEnabled` property to `NO`.

With scrolling disabled, you can still adjust the scroll position programmatically, but the user can not scroll.  This should work just fine for you.

Comment: How could i not think about that! Probably been overworking! Thanks!